# Balmer Continuum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I'm trying to simulate the Balmer series emission lines and am trying to compute the wavelengths.  The Rydberg formula does this fine, up until the point where you're trying to model the spectrum at the edge (3646 Å) where the theoretical upper level is infinity.  The way the Rydberg formula is set up, are an infinite number of lines up to the edge.  Of course, you can't simulate a spectrum of an infinite number of lines, and despite their lower energies, they still create a large spike at the edge.

My question: should there be a large spike in emission at the edge? Or does the probability of transition decrease more-rapidly as you approach the edge?

Answer (score 0):

The transition probability depends on the (square of the) overlap integral involving the wave functions of the upper and lower state. If you go to very high states (approaching the series limit) there is hardly any overlap anymore, so the transition probability decreases strongly, approximately like 1/n<sup>3.2</sup> with increasing quantum number n. And for sufficently high n the lifetime of the level becomes consequently so long that that collisions interfere and the electron can't properly decay anymore radiatively, so the intensity of the lines diminishes even faster. This more than compensates for the 'bunching' effect at the series limit (which goes only like $n^3$)